# how to create imageview half of screen in xml

Tags: android

i want to show image view half of screen and rest of screen i will show multiple textview like this

> [image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

     android:padding="6dip">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip" 

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Weight concept

Here is the code below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- put your imagebackground image -->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="firstText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="secondText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:text="thirdText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Relative Layout, use a LinearLayout and use weightsum attribute.

Sample,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application" />
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide all Screen in two part First is imageview and Other layout take all other view and set imageview weight and other layout weight=1 and take both height fill parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: give me progralically example please

Answer (score 0):

use weight sum for parent view and implement `android:layout_weight="50"` for 1st child layout and same for another child....

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="My Application" />

</LinearLayout>
```